# Checar compatibilidade com navegadores

Tags: navegador-de-internet

Como vocês fazem para checar compatibilidade dos sites nos diversos navegadores?
Vocês usam ferramentas online, quais? Ou testam por conta própria?
Alguma experiência para relatar sobre isso?
Atualmente precisamos sempre estar atentos a questão de compatibilidade, pois não podemos esperar usuários de *Firefox* somente, mas também de *Chrome*, *Opera*, *Safari*..

Comment: Eu utilizo a [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) para testar se o browser possui novos recursos do HTML e CSS. [Esse artigo](http://tableless.com.br/utilizando-a-biblioteca-modernizr/) pode ser útil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os [polyfills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) são uma maneira de utilizar código moderno em browsers antigos, mas saber exatamante o que deve ser tratado é muito dificil ai [a Mozilla criou Polyfill as a Service](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/11/an-easier-way-of-using-polyfills/).

Funciona basicamente assim; você insere um script cujo URL aponta para este serviço e  junto do request do script o browser manda o header [user-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) que identifica qual browser o usuário esta usando, e baseado nesta informação é servido um script que faz o polyfill das funcionalidades modernas que o seu browser não contempla.

Diferente do modernizr que apenas detecta as funcionalidades que estão ausentes *este serviço de fato preenche as lacunas*.

Se você quiser dar uma hackeada no projeto o repositório no GitHub é esse aqui; https://github.com/Financial-Times/polyfill-service

Eu não testei este serviço mas me parece BEM promissor.

Comment: Uau, no mínimo interessante..Pelo visto a Mozilla facilitou bastante, pois os polyfills existem, e para varias necessidades eles atendem, uns inserem elementos no lugar dos não reconhecidos pelos navegadores antigos(nav,section), outros corrigem css..
Pelo que vi, com esse serviço Polyfill é possível usar um único script, que é capaz de usar todos os Polyfills necessários com base no navegador do usuário, então, isso quer dizer que, quem acessa com browsers modernos, não têm necessidade de ter trabalhando este plugins, e é isso que a Mozilla fez, deixou o trabalho apenas para quem precisava!

Comment: Acredito que seja +- por ai, vou tentar usar, e ver se perde muito rendimento para os navegadores antigos, mas acredito que se for sites pequenos, não é preciso usar um plugin, apenas pequenas correções já são necessários..

Comment: Como diz no artigo, você pode especificar só o que você quer. Se você precisa de poucas coisas você mesmo pode implementar os polyfills no seu javascript! Depois que testar posta um feedback aqui